# iPhone doesn't have Default-Portrait.png and Default-Landscape.png files?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a universal iPhone/iPad App.

According to Apple the two following files are *ONLY* for iPad:
Default-Portrait.png
Default-Landscape.png

My question is, what are the portrait/landscape files I should use for iPhone? I see that iPhone only has Default.png, so it cannot distinguish between Portrait and Landscape like iPad?

Answer (score 2):

Apple hasn't made an official way to have multiple Default images for iPhone apps. You're gonna have to either make the Default.png a portrait image or landscape image.

Comment: Pretty sure the iPhone only has one default orientation and you can set a default of Landscape if it's a game or something. The default is Portrait but you can set the default to be Landscape in the info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

Springboard (the launcher app) only works in portrait, so the user will "always" be launching your app from portrait mode. If your app supports only landscape orientation, you should just use a landscape image to encourage them to turn the phone the right way around.